# display: inline-block, span does not align properly

Tags: html, css

I've tried the `vertical-align` property, but failed to align the `span` in the middle:

```css
.foo {
 width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: powderblue;
 display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.bar {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <img class="img" src="http://dmrctt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Address-FTN-Image_1322320725.jpg" alt="">
  <span class="bar"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
</div>
```

I've also tried with the `display: inline-block` and expected that I could now align the `span` in the middle of the `div`. Why is this not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default veritcal alignment of inline elements is baseline. So change it to something that fits what you need, like middle.

```css
.foo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar {
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <img class="img" src="http://dmrctt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Address-FTN-Image_1322320725.jpg" alt="">
  <span class="bar"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"center" is not a valid value for vertical-align, I think you mean "middle".

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Also, display:inline-block is doing nothing for you there, as it should be on the child elements (if at all), not the container.

All you need to solve this is use vertical-align:middle on the img.

```css
.foo {
 width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: powderblue;
}

.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <img class="img" src="http://dmrctt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Address-FTN-Image_1322320725.jpg" alt="">
  <span class="bar"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
</div>
```